# PtrSafe no longer supported in Outlook 2007 - re-editing macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm currently considering using a macro for Outlook 2007 and read somewhere that **PtrSafe is no longer supported**.

Any idea what I can replace it with?

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, _
ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Private Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Private Const FLAGS As Long = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
Private Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1

Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim ReminderWindowHWnd As Variant
On Error Resume Next
ReminderWindowHWnd = FindWindowA(vbNullString, "1 Reminder")
SetWindowPos ReminderWindowHWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you read that PtrSafe is no longer supported, but that is incorrect.
But you should look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I followed that link, suggested by Charles Williams, and created this code which solves the compilation error:

```
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
    ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, _
    ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
    ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, _
    ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
#End If
```